# jquery filtering selections with the filter function

Tags: javascript, jquery

So according to this [jQuery documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/) "In order to get the best performance using :password, first select elements with a standard jQuery selector, then use .filter( ":password" ), or precede the pseudo-selector with a tag name or some other selector."

So I comply and filter out the selection using the filter function but it returns 0; no elements were selected. Why is this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>jQuery</title>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var t = $("form").filter(":password");

    $("body").append(t.length);


});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="password" name="file" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `:password` are `input`s and your selector is a `form`. `filter` works on the current collection. You can use `find`.

Comment: Well that was pretty damn embarrassing. Thanks.

Comment: I would do : `$('form input[type="password"]')`

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to query `<input>` elements and filter on those:

```
$('form input').filter(':password');
```

Right now you're selecting all `<form>` elements and filtering them for `:password` types (and there won't be any).

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have any forms of type password.

You could use one of the following:
`$('form input').filter(":password")`
or
`$("form").find("input:password")`